# Oscola LaTeX package won't display Table of Legislation

Tags: indexing, oscola

I have the following LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=oscola, ibidstyle=uc, ibidtracker=true, backend=biber, indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{/Projects/Agape Chambers/llm-a.bib}

\usepackage[splitindex, nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=cases, title={Table of cases}]
\makeindex[name=legislation, title={Table of Legislation}]

\DeclareIndexAssociation{gbcases}{cases}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{encases}{cases}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{primary}{legislation}
\begin{document}    

\section*{Assessment of liability under the Occupiers' Liability Act 1957\footcite{ola1957}}

\subsection*{Is the Defendant on OCCUPIER of PREMISES?}

\printbibliography[
  nottype=commentary,
  nottype=jurisdiction,
  nottype=legislation,
  nottype=legal]

 \printindex[cases]
 \printindex[legislation]
 \end{document}
```

And here is the bib file I'm using.

```
@Legislation{ola1957,
    Title                    = {Occupiers' Liability Act 1957},
    Entrysubtype             = {primary},
    Keywords                 = {en},
    Pagination               = {section},
    Shorthand                = {OLA 1957},
    Owner                    = {user},
    Timestamp                = {2018.11.13}
 }
```

However, when I run compile (using TeXStudio), the table of legislation does not appear. Can anyone help?

Comment: After `\end{document}` in your code is `@Legislation{...`. You don't expect to see that, do you?

Comment: The LaTeX and bib entry are in two differnt files. I've amended the post to make this clearer.

Comment: Use `\DeclareIndexAssociation{enprimleg}{legislation}` to send English primary legislation to your `legislation` index. Table 1 in the documentation lists all the built-in category names, called `hooks`, for the virtual indexes (indices).